# Inheritance of Generic typing in python not type checking correctly

Tags: python

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my type hinting correctly
I want the code to look something like this:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
K = TypeVar("K")


class Mapping(Generic[T, K]):
    def __init__(self, mapping: dict[T, K]):
        self.mapping = mapping


class IntListMap(Mapping[int, list[K]]):
    pass


foo: IntListMap[str] = IntListMap({0: ["", ""]})
```

however I could only get the typing to work if I did this:

```
class IntListMap(Map[int, list[K]], Generic[K]):
    pass


foo: IntListMap[int, list[str]] = IntListMap({0: ["", ""]})
```

Is there any way I can get around having to type hint the super class?

Comment: I have the opposite result. I can't convince the type checker that two arguments is correct, even with your second snippet. The first code works fine. Running mypy 0.800 on Python 3.7.9. What type checker are you using?

Comment: I’m using pycharm’s recent version with python 3.10